# How to separate integer/float and string part of a given string?

Tags: python

Given string `"5mins"`, I want to separate them something like `[5, 'mins']`. I have tried doing:

```
>>> re.findall(r"\d+|\D+", '5mins')
['5', 'mins']
```

which seems to do good but:

```
>>> def separate(string):
...    return re.findall(r"\d+|\D+", string)
...
>>> print(separate('3hours'))
['3', 'hours']
>>> print(separate('7secs'))
['7', 'secs']
>>> print(separate('now'))
['now']
```

The problem with this method is I get `ValueError` if I have done assignment:

```
>>> number, unit = separate('now')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

The all I here want is to get a *list* of `number` and `unit`. If there is no number then I should get an empty string, so that I can process the time further.

Additionally it's good if `number` is not a string, like above `separate()` function returns.

Comment: No, it's still a string, even if it contains a number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> re.match(r"(\d+)?(\D+)?$", '5mins').groups()
('5', 'mins')
>>> re.match(r"(\d+)?(\D+)?$", 'now').groups()
(None, 'now')
```

Comment: Dealing with regex has always been difficult to me. I usually run away form regex. Where did you learnt it? :)

Comment: The hard way. Practice, practice, practice.